# Refine SQL date-range query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Attempting to query for when, given parameters @startDate and @endDate, a record occurs in as much of the time frame as is supplied. I have a functional where clause below, but I suspect it can be more direct.

If an end date is supplied, records will not be selected from after that date. If a start date is supplied, records will not be selected from before that date. If no dates are supplied all records will be selected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE
   (
      (@startDate IS NULL AND ((@endDate IS NULL) OR (myTable.[recordDate] <= @endDate)))
      OR
      (@endDate IS NULL AND ((@startDate IS NULL) OR (myTable.[recordDate] >= @startDate)))
      OR
      (myTable.[recordDate] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could workaround with `ISNULL` function like below:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.[recordDate] >= ISNULL(@startDate, '01/01/1900')
AND   myTable.[recordDate] <= ISNULL(@endDate, getDate())
```

This query will select all the rows that are either:

- Between @startDate and @endDate inclusive of both
- Between @startDate and current date time if @endDate is null
- Between 01/01/1900 if @startDate is null and todays' date time if @endDate is null
- Between 01/01/1900 if @startDate is null and @endDate

Comment: One change I might make to this solution is setting a replacement value for endDate to "the end of time." Any suggestions on how to set this up? 
   @user3537535 suggested using a date like "12/31/9999" in his answer
   Another forum suggested using max(myTable.[recordDate])

Comment: That's right. You have right set of options there. I thought records less that just now but you are right you could use '12/31/9999' instead of getdate().

Answer (score 0):

Setup a temp tableceiling with floor and ceiling and join to table on date BETWEEN floor and ceiling. Setup your unbounded conditions(NULL)as 1/1/1900 and 12/31/9999. A colleague showed me this recently and it worked.